# Is it possible to move Skype's file / chronology to another folder?

Tags: skype

I want to change the default folder where Skype put it's file.

I mean the files of the chat cronology which Skype puts here:

`C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Skype`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

1. First you need to have a profile folder in the default location (%APPDATA%\Skype), by simply signing in to your profile at least once.
2. Sign out and Quit from Skype, otherwise you'll get File in use problems
3. Move the profile folder from the %APPDATA%\Skype to a secure location (TrueCrypt drive, or other drives), for example T:\tech_engineer
4. Create a symbolic link from the Skype data folder to the new location by executing on a Command Prompt this command:
   On a Windows XP machine, after downloading the Junction utility from the Microsoft website, type:

junction T:[new location name] %appdata%\skype[skype username]

On a Windows 7 machine:

mklink /D %appdata%\skype[skype username] T:[new location name]